# Limpiar input despues de ejecutar evento keypress

Tags: javascript

Tengo un evento añadido a la ventana:

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    
    if(code == 78 || code == 110)
        prepararJuego();
    
    return false;
});
```

Cuando se presiona una tecla, a un input se le añade el focus y le agrega como valor la tecla que se presionó, y lo que necesito es que al presionar una tecla solo se añada el focus a ese input.

Por ejemplo si se presiona la tecla **n** en el input al que se le hace el focus en el atributo value pone como valor la **n**.

```
var inputLetra = document.querySelector("#letra");

function prepararJuego()
{
    inputElemento.focus();
}
```

Ya he intentando poner la siguiente linea y no funciona:

```
inputElemento.value = "";
```

Como puedo solucionar esto??

Comment: Disculpa, no entiendo. `focus()` te funciona o no? No sabemos qué es `inputElemento`, eso sí.

Comment: @Alfabravo funciona pero en el input añade en el atributo value la tecla presionada. La variable inputElemento guarda el input que tengo en el documento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```js
window.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

    if(code == 78 || code == 110){
        prepararJuego();
        e.preventDefault(); //<--Aqui
    }
    return false;
});


function prepararJuego()
{
    inputElemento.focus();
}
```

```html
<input id="inputElemento">
```

Ojo!! que el evento [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) esta obsoleto

Comment: Gracias, asi si funciono!!!!